# FlatList is slow when the list is large (100s of items) - state change performance issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

`FlatList` is slow when the data set is large (100s of items). Each click on an item's `checkbox` takes around **2 seconds**. Actually, the first click on a checkbox takes around a second; then, it increases by 20% till it reaches 2.5 seconds. It stays at 2.5 seconds for any clicks after that. It seems that the bottleneck is `changing state`. Is there any way to improve the performance? Please, see a simplified code, which demonstrates the issue below.

```js
const TestScreen = () => {
    // Build a testing data set. 
    // In the actual application, the data set is stored in Redux. 
    let contactList = []; 
    for (let i = 0; i < 700; i++) { contactList.push({ mobileNo: i.toString() }); } 

    const [contactPhoneNumberList2, setContactPhoneNumberList2] = React.useState([]);

    const _onPress = async (item) => {
        // The following step takes no time because the number of selected items is very small! 
        const indexOfSelectedItem = contactPhoneNumberList2.findIndex(element => element === item.mobileNo);        

        // Get the current time BEFORE calling the state-changing step
        const now = new Date(); 

        // The user clicked on an already selected item -> let's unselect it (remove it from the list of selected items)
        if (indexOfSelectedItem > -1) {
            let abc = [ ...contactPhoneNumberList2 ]; 
            abc.splice(indexOfSelectedItem, 1);

            // Updating state takes around 2 seconds 
            // await is used below to help identify the bottleneck. It is NOT part of the production code. 
            await setContactPhoneNumberList2(abc); // <<< PROBLEM <<< 
            
            // Get the current time AFTER calling the state-changing step
            const now2 = new Date(); 
            console.log("state-changin took (milliseconds):", now2 - now, "onPress - IF - after state change", ); 
        }
        // The user clicked on an unselected item -> let's select it (add it to the list of selected items)
        else {
            // Updating state takes around 2 seconds 
            // await is used below to help identify the bottleneck. It is NOT part of the production code. 
            await setContactPhoneNumberList2(contactPhoneNumberList2.concat([item.mobileNo])); // <<< PROBLEM <<< 
            
            // Get the current time AFTER calling the state-changing step
            const now2 = new Date(); 
            console.log("state-changin took (milliseconds):", now2 - now, "onPress - IF - after state change", ); 
        }
    }; 

    const _renderItem = ({ item, index, }) => {
        // The following step takes no time because the number of selected items is very small! 
        const itemWasSelected = contactPhoneNumberList2.find(element => element === item.mobileNo);     

        return (
            <ListItem>
                <ListItem.CheckBox checked={itemWasSelected} onPress={() => _onPress(item)}/>
                <ListItem.Content>
                    <ListItem.Title>{item.mobileNo}</ListItem.Title>
                 </ListItem.Content>
            </ListItem>
        );
    };

    return (
        <FlatList
            data={contactList} 

            // just in case, the natural key (item.mobileNo) is repeated, the index is appended to it
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.mobileNo + index.toString()} 
        
            renderItem={_renderItem}

            // I tried the following, but none of them seems to helpful, in this case 
            // removeClippedSubviews={false}
            // initialNumToRender={5}
            // maxToRenderPerBatch={10} // good 
            // windowSize={10}

            // getItemLayout={_getItemLayout}
        />
    );  
}; 

export default TestScreen;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem isn't specific to FlatList or React Native. The issue is caused by your state change causing every item in the list to re-render on every change.

There are multiple ways to solve this:

1. The simplest solution would be to move state down to a deeper component, this would mean state updates are isolated to a single component, so you'll only have one render per state change.

   This likely isn't practical because I assume you probably need access to your selected state in `TestScreen` in order for it to be used for other purposes.
2. Memoize the component rendered in `renderItem`. This will mean that with each state update `TestScreen` will render, but then only the items that have changed will re-render.

Here's an example of how to achieve #2 and an [Expo Snack example](https://snack.expo.dev/@levibuzolic/petrified-blueberries) to play with:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const contactList = new Array(700)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, index) => ({ mobileNo: index.toString() }));

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const handlePress = useCallback((item) => {
    // Using the state setter callback will give you access to the previous state, this has two advantages:
    //   1. You don't need to pass anything to the dependency array of the `useCallback`, which means this
    //      function will remain stable between renders.
    //   2. This will prevent any issues with rapid actions causing lost state because of stale data.
    setSelected((previousState) => {
      const index = previousState.indexOf(item.mobileNo);

      if (index !== -1) {
        const cloned = [...previousState];
        cloned.splice(index, 1);
        return cloned;
      } else {
        return [...previousState, item.mobileNo];
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={contactList}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.mobileNo + index.toString()}
      // Important: All props being passed to <Item> must be stable/memoized
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Item
          // Only the `checked` property will change for the changed items
          checked={selected.includes(item.mobileNo)}
          onPress={handlePress}
          item={item}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Memo will prevent each instance of this component from re-rendering if all of its props stay the same.
const Item = React.memo((props) => (
  <ListItem>
    <ListItem.CheckBox
      checked={props.checked}
      onPress={() => props.onPress(props.item)}
    />
    <ListItem.Content>
      <ListItem.Title>{props.item.mobileNo}</ListItem.Title>
    </ListItem.Content>
  </ListItem>
));
```

I also noticed in your example you were `await`ing the state setter calls. This is not required, React state setters are not asynchronous functions.

Comment: It also works using `FlatList` and `CheckBox` in NativeBase. The `CheckBox` in NativeBase does not have `onPress()` props, which you can use to wrap it into `Pressable()` or handle ut in the `onChange()` props.

Answer (score 1):

use useMemo, memo and useCallback will help you to prevent rerender in your list and for large list  in your app

```
      const keyExtractor = useCallback(item => item.id);

      const renderItem = useCallback(({item, index}) => {
        return <Item item={item} index={index} />;
      }, []);

      const [Messages, setMessage] = useState([]);

      const myFlatii = useMemo(() => {
        return (
          <FlatList
            data={Messages}
            extraData={Messages}
            style={styleofFlat}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig.current}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
            updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}
            ListFooterComponent={ListFooterComponent}
            keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
            onEndReached={onEndReached}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
          />
        );
      }, [Messages]);
    
      return (
        <>
          <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: AppColors.Black}}>
            {myFlatii}
          </SafeAreaView>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    const Item = memo(
      ({item, index, notPreviewableLink, linkPreviewData}) => {
        return <RenderChatItem message={item} index={index} />;
      },
      (r1, r2) => {
        return r1.item.id === r2.item.id;
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Flatlist item in memo, and function that changes checkbox state in useCallback, so only item that is changed is being rerendered and not the whole flatlist.